# How are statistical decision theory and statistical learning theory related?

Tags: decision-theory, statistical-learning

[This](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.115.9500&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper attempts to contrast the basic elements of statistical learning theory and statistical decision theory, but I'm still confused about how the two are related.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the relation between statistics theory and decision theory?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9208/what-is-the-relation-between-statistics-theory-and-decision-theory)

Comment: @Emre That question is about the relation between Statistics and Decision Theory whereas I'm trying to understand the relation between [Statistical Learning Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_learning_theory) and Statistical Decision Theory.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the Wikipedia articles? Decision theory is a subset of or problem in statistical learning, in my view;  both driven by statistics -- data. It concerns the optimal making of decisions such as choosing between alternatives, once or over a period of time (possibly without termination), or deciding when to stop an experiment, etc. Statistical learning theory is a much broader concept. It is the most popular paradigm for machine learning. Maybe you know that?

Comment: I hadn't heard the term "Statistical Learning Theory" before and came across it while studying about [VC Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapnik%E2%80%93Chervonenkis_theory). The formalisms in [Statistical Learning Theory](http://wang.ist.psu.edu/course/05/IST597/papers/Vapnik_learn.pdf) seemed similar to the ones I studied before in Statistical Decision Theory.